# Graphite data display delay

Tags: graphite

I'm sending 4 metrics every minute from another server to the server hosting graphite. I've set up graphite & grafana and am able to see the data in grafana. However, I notice that there's about a 3-minute delay from the time I sent the metric to the time I see it in Grafana.

I'm using graphite and Grafana for a real-time display and is setting Grafana to auto-refresh every 10s. It's a bit unusual to have this 3-min delay. I doubt if the network is causing that much delay. Is there anyway to look into why this delay is so high?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out there's some issue in the graphite version I was using. The answer is here: https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/254964

Answer (score 0):

If you point your graphite setup (in graphite-web local_settings.py) to a memcached cluster, metrics are cached there for (by default) 1 min.
It could explain part of the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add that graphite doesn't show last point from rrd, thats why you can had delay.

/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/readers/rrd.py in "fetch" method you need to comment 
rows.pop() if this problem is important for you